# Error when usign sum function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells (just a simple column) which id like to use the sum function on in vba. The cells are on a separate worksheet from the one I used originally when I created the macro. Its returning a runtime error 1004. Im new to vba so im probably formatting something wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(16, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(12, 3)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always be sure to qualify `Range()` **and** `Cells()` with the worksheet:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(16, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 3), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(12, 3)))
```

Or, perhaps a little easier to read:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
   .Cells(16, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(4, 3), .Cells(12, 3)))
End With
```

Note when using  `With`, the `.` is vital! Without that, it's just going to refer to the `ActiveSheet`'s `Range()` or `Cells()`, likely causing an error.

Comment: Thanks so much! Fixed now.